# Special character "!" and "@" in password and username respectively

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, python-requests

I am trying to send requests.post in Python which has a

```
username = "devoops123@mdf.nct.com"
password = "ChangemeinNv!"
```

My script has

```
start_build_url = 'http://{0}/jenkins/job/{1}/job/{2}/buildWithParameters?token={3}&{4}'.format(
    jenkins_uri, folder_name, job_name, build_token, build_param)
r = requests.post(
    start_build_url, data={
        'username': 'auth_username','password': 'auth_pass'}
)
```

I get a `401 Authentication` issue when I execute my script

While passing the password as argument to my script I have tried by the following, but nothing seems to help:

- `%21` instead of `!` and `%40` for `@`
- Escaping both the special charc by `\`
- Enclosing the arguments in `" "`

Comment: are you sending `'auth_username'` as the post data or what?

Comment: Frequently you can use something like base64 encoding to encode the strings so this doesn't happen.  Does whatever service you're interacting with support that?

Comment: The password and username are madeup

Comment: @PatrickHaugh are you saying to user auth_pass.encode('utf-8') ? This i have already done

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: that's *highly* dependent on the specific API. It so happens that HTTP Basic Auth uses base64, yes, but simply guessing at encodings is not going to get you far.

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins expects you to send the username and password using the [*Basic authentication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) feature of HTTP. `requests` can [handle this natively](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication). See the [Jenkins *Remove access API* documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-RemoteAPIandsecurity):

> When your Jenkins is secured, you can use HTTP BASIC authentication to authenticate remote API requests.

Just put the username and password in a tuple passed in as the `auth` argument:

```
start_build_url = 'http://{0}/jenkins/job/{1}/job/{2}/buildWithParameters?token={3}&{4}'.format(
    jenkins_uri, folder_name, job_name, build_token, build_param)
r = requests.post(
    start_build_url, auth=(username, password),
)
```

Neither the `username` nor the `password` values need to be escaped, leave that to `requests` to worry about for you.

Comment: There's also a python wrapper library  called `python-jenkins` that can be used. https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/